# If a flywheel is spinning at say 1,000 rpm, would an input of 500 rpm would actually slow it down?

Tags: energy, entropy, kinetic-theory

When a flywheel is stationery, an input of 500 rpm would translate to less than 500 rpm in the flywheel considering entropy, but what happens if the flywheel is already running at 1000 rpm, wouldn't the torque influence the input? How then can we store an input of 500 rpm? Thanks.

Comment: How would you "input" 500 RPM?

Comment: I am not just struggling to understand what you mean by "input of angular velocity" but how entropy is coming into play here. A flywheel is not a thermodynamic system.

Comment: Maybe this is of help: kinetic energy of a flywheel $E_{kin}={1\over2}I\omega^2$ is similar to kinetic energy of a moving body $E_{kin}={1\over2}mv^2$, where the moment of inertia $I$ takes the role of the mass and angular velocity $\omega$ is used similar to linear velocity  $v$. When we apply a torque $\tau$ to a flywheel, the angular acceleration $\alpha$ is given by $\tau = I\alpha$, in parallel with Newton's second law, i.e. torque has the same function for rotary motion as force has for linear motion.

Comment: @Peter: say a motor is running at 500 rpm, what would happen if we use this as an energy input to the already running flywheel? As RaSullivan has pointed out there would be a backload being the flywheel actually transferring the energy into the motor to speed it up. So to put less rpm into an already moving flywheel defeats its purpose. I was trying to figure out how much energy is needed to 'top up' an already moving flywheel.

Comment: @ CuriousOne: Pardon me, a better word would be friction and waste energy. Input as in rotating movement.

Comment: You would only waste energy if you don't design your coupling mechanism correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to input in your terms 500rpm you are required to input the actual shaft rpm Plus 500 you seek to add. You must charge your input to the systems energy level. So to answer your question yes your  input of 500rpm would slow down the shaft rpm.

Comment: It should be realized that you would find it impossible to apply an input source to the shaft and the prime mover supplying your  500rpm would in fact be /back loaded by 500rpm, the difference.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now. To think that I could put in a less rpm input to top up the flywheel would actually produce a backload per your answer and takes the energy out instead.